# input_sentences = [text.split("") for text in df["text"].values.tolist()]

Tags: python

I am new to coding, can someone please explain to me what this line of code is doing:

```
input_sentences = [text.split("") for text in df["text"].values.tolist()]
```

where `text` is a column containing sentences in my excel dataset df

Comment: _where text is a column containing sentences in my excel dataset df_ That doesn't make a ton of sense, can you share some more context for this? Also, which part of that line of code are you struggling with? Have you tried breaking it down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df["text"].values.tolist()
```

Transforms your column 'test' in a list of the values you had in the column.

```
[text.split("") for text in df["text"].values.tolist()]
```

This line takes each element text of the previous list and split the words by the char "". Here it is empty. If you split by "," or by "." you will have for text="blabla,blabla"

text.split(",") will give you a list : ["blabla","blabla"]

So in the end you will have a list of list of words contained in your dataframe's column.

Answer (score 1):

to understand this line what knowlede you require

1. list comprehension[link1](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension)
2. tolist function[link2](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-series-tolist/)
3. pandas series[link3](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-series/)
4. spilt()[link4](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-split/)

Now Jump to our code

```
  input_sentences = [text.split("") for text in df["text"].values.tolist()]
```

Understand step by step

```
  df["text"].values.tolist()
```

df['text] is series which define using index and value from that we are extracting only value then it is converted into list

```
  for text in df["text"].values.tolist()
```

this is just for loop which is iterating our list and each single value from list inserted into text

```
text.split("")
```

from above the value inserted in text are seperated by space  and at last stored inside 2d list